# Regex validate this string

Tags: regex, regex-group

Suppose I want to validate request

```
item-dsaK123 - request
item-dsaK123*item-Dslw123 - request
item-dsaK123*item-Dslw123*item-ABcd123 - request
item-dsaK132*item-Ddsw532 - request
```

How can I validate those strings:

- no empty string
- each item must start with item with dash in the middle and unique identifier consist of a-z, A-Z, digit in random order.
- each item can be concatenated to show relationship but it is separated by "*".

valid:

```
item-dsaK123 
item-dsaK123*item-Dslw123 
item-dsaK123*item-Dslw123*item-ABcd123 
item-dsaK132*item-Ddsw532
```

invalid:

```
item-dsaK132+item-Ddsw532*item-ABcd123 
item-dsaK132+
""(empty string)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share your attempt as a [mre]? What RegExp flavor are you using? See [ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use this regex, which matches a string containing an item, followed by 0 or more of `*` followed by another item:

```
^item-[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\*item-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\s?$
```

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/F91rCK/2)

Note I've put a trailing `\s?` on the regex because some of the strings in the question data end with a space. If that's not the case IRL, you can remove it from the regex.